# Nonlinear frequency response

Tags: nonlinear

I am trying to reproduce the result of [this](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/computationalnonlinear/article-abstract/9/3/031016/371798/Modeling-and-Analysis-of-an-Electrically-Actuated) paper, namely Figure 10 which depicts the solution of equation 64 given as,

[image]

qmax is the steady state solution of the oscillatory equation given. I tried to reproduce the result using the code below:

```
data = {Vac -> 0.01 Cos[\[CapitalOmega] t], Vdc -> 100, c -> 0};
 eq = q''[t] + c*q'[t] + 864.82*q[t] + 21.78 q[t]^2 + 142.58 q[t]^3     == 
  45.31 ((2 Vac)/Vdc + Vac^2/Vdc^2) + (1 + (2 Vac)/Vdc + Vac^2/
  Vdc^2)*(123.51 q[t] + 74.09 q[t]^2 + 1424.72 q[t]^3 - 
  122.45 q[t]^4);
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eq /. data, q[0] == 0, q'[0] == 0}, 
 q, {t, .1, 100}, {\[CapitalOmega]}];
lst={#, Max[q[#][Range[80, 100, .1]] /. sol]} & /@ Range[20, 30, .1];

ListPlot[lst];
```

As you can see the figure is different. I appreciate if you can help in getting the same figure (figure 10), shown below

[image]

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked into the paper and your code, and I think there are two main issues.

1. I couldn't have deduced how you obtained the value $V_{dc}=100$, and I also think this is why your results are off. However, neither couldn't I have found the correct value in the paper ($\alpha_2 V^2 = 45, V = V_{ac} + V_{dc}, V_{ac}=0.01$ – this still leaves unknown $\alpha$ and $V_{dc}$).
2. Your timerange when solving the DE might be too short for some parameter values (very small $c$).

I have tried by some trial-and-error to deduce that $V_{dc} \approx 5$ gives approximately the same results. Be careful, they used two approximation methods (Chebyshev and Taylor) which have slightly different positions of the peak, $\Omega_{\text{Ch.}} \approx 27.1$ and $\Omega_{\text{Tay.}} \approx 27.4$. However, you are solving the DE without approximations and the peak occurs somewhere in between at $\Omega \approx 27.2$.

```
data = {Vac -> 0.01 Cos[\[CapitalOmega] t], Vdc -> 5};
eq = q''[t] + c*q'[t] + 864.82*q[t] + 21.78 q[t]^2 + 142.58 q[t]^3 == 
   45.31 ((2 Vac)/Vdc + Vac^2/Vdc^2) + (1 + (2 Vac)/Vdc + 
       Vac^2/Vdc^2)*(123.51 q[t] + 74.09 q[t]^2 + 1424.72 q[t]^3 - 
       122.45 q[t]^4);
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eq /. data, q[0] == 0, q'[0] == 0}, 
   q, {t, .1, 200}, {\[CapitalOmega], c}];

cs = {0.05, 0.1, 0.25};
\[CapitalOmega]s = Sort[Union[Range[26.5, 28.5, .1], Range[27, 27.4, .02]]];
lst = Table[{\[Omega], First@NMaximize[{q[\[Omega], c][t] /. sol, 190 < t < 200}, t]}, 
   {\[Omega], \[CapitalOmega]s}, {c, cs}];
lst2 = Partition[Transpose@lst, Dimensions[cs]];

ListPlot[First@lst2, PlotRange -> {0, 0.12}, Joined -> True, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotLegends -> cs]
```

[image: Plot]

I hope you find any of these comments valuable. Note, however, that there might be some more efficient (faster) ways of calculating the maxima; I haven't looked into that.

Comment: Many thanks bro. You saved me a lot of time and efforts. I appreciate your help. Many thanks again.